# How can I remove the Python Shell window while using Tkinter?

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, tkinter

Hello to the Stack Overflow Community! I am an amateur coder & student and am developing a UI for my superiors at my 'school.' I have been bothered by the Python Shell window opening as well and was wondering if there was a way to remove that window without having my Tkinter program shut down.

Thanks!

Comment: Windows or Mac?

Comment: DYZ: Mac OSX Sierra

Comment: you mean `"command line"` like `"cmd.exe/terminal/console"`, not `"Python Shell"` ? BTW: why do you set tag `python-idle` ?

Comment: @furas I've used the tag python-idle because I am using IDLE's GUI to code. I mean the Python Shell that opens up when you launch Python 3 on any OS. When I run my code (from a .py file), it overlaps the Shell over my Tkinter window, which bothers me and subtracts from the user experience.

Comment: When your script is run in "production" it won't be from IDLE's shell. Trying running it the way if will be.

Comment: has IDLE something to do with your problem ? If not then it doesn't matter that you use IDLE to code. How do you run this script ? Do you click on script, run in console `python script` (as most of people) or in IDLE ? If you run in IDLE then don't bother `Python Shell` - IDLE is used only to develop code. Later you don't need IDLE to run it and you will no see Python Shell.

Comment: @furas Can you reply to the actual post so I can mark this problem as solved? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Rename you main script to have the extension `.pyw`. This file type, when executed, is by default run by pythonw.exe instead of python.exe, and it doesn't show the console.

You will need some means to report debug errors, though. Just an advice.

Comment: it would work on Windows, but not on Mac/Linux - OP use Mac OSX Sierra

Comment: The OP is on Mac. There is no `.pyw` on Mac.

Comment: How do we remove the console when we deployed our app using "pyintstaller"?

Answer (score 0):

If you run in IDLE then don't bother Python Shell - IDLE is used only to develop code.

Later you don't need IDLE to run it and you will no see Python Shell.